# Is Blazor wasm compatible with InteropServices.NativeLibrary methods?

Tags: blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0, c#-native-library

I try to call methods into a native dynamic library (c++) through a .Net 8.0 class library interface with InteropServices.NativeLibrary from a blazor wasm but I have an exception : "NativeLibrary.Load("mycpplib.dll")" Not supported platform exception ...

I tried to publish the .Net 8.0 class library (used as interface between wasm and native library) with AOT but the result is the same.

I don't know if I have reached a limitation or if there is a solution to call native library with InteropServices.NativeLibrary in wasm context?

Thanks for your help :)

Publish .Net 8.0 class library with AOT => doesn't work.

Call from Blazor server => Works but is not the goal.

Comment: Can you compile the C++ to Wasm?

Comment: @HenkHolterman thanks for your help. I think wasm compilation could be ok if I link my native library directly into my blazor project but I must use an intermediate .Net library who load my native library with NativeLibrary.Load("mycpplib.dll"). The problem is this method need a relative path to the native library and Blazor wasm can't access to a relative file.